Reset selected swatches in configurable product
I need to create a "Reset" button, that will reset selected options on the front end in a configurable product, to the state, where no attribute was selected. So for example I have selected these options https://imgur.com/yRskB8d, then I click "Reset" and it reset all selected options to this state https://imgur.com/vdkmFyu.
I tried to find any info about this, and all I found is:
Magento\Catalog\Model\Product.php
public function reset()
{
    $this->unlockAttributes();
    $this->_clearData();
    return $this;
}

But I couldn't track down where it is used.

I used swatch-renderer.js for this:

Create new function
     _Reset: function () {
     var $widget = this,
         controls = $widget.element.find('div[data-attribute-id]'),
         selected = controls.filter('[data-option-selected]');

     console.log('_Reset');

     // Enable all options
     $widget._Rewind(controls);
     controls.find('div.selected[data-option-id]').removeClass('selected');
     controls.find('.swatch-attribute-selected-option').text('');
     $('div[data-attribute-id][data-option-selected]').removeAttr('data-option-selected');}


Create trigger
         $('#reset-attr').click(function(){
             $widget._Reset();
         });



